# How to map Object field:value to attribute list?

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

ST has `add(String name, Object value)`, but what if i want to populate ST attributes with data from POJO?

```
class User {
public String id;
public String link;
public String key;
}
```

So, i want to type something like `ST.add(new User(...))` and get result:

```
ST.add("id", id);
ST.add("link", link);
...
```

As workaround i use Jackon ObjectMapper to map User.class to Map.class and then populate ST object with forEach.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Frontear I want ST to replace vars in template "some <id>, some <link>, sone <key>" without manually adding attributes(add("id", o.getId()). I want ST to use reflection and pass this key:value attrs based on fields name

Comment: @callmedope then where are you failing? There are a lot of questions in the internet that ask about how to read files from POJO with reflection